# TYPO3 frontend user login redirect to URL

Tags: redirect, authentication, content-management-system, typo3, frontend

A customers' TYPO3 website has gone online and is now accessible via 4 separate URLs. The sites' structure looks like this:

```
Entry point
|
|-- Example 1 (www.example1.at, group1)
|-- Example 2 (www.example2.at, group2)
|-- Example 3 (www.example3.at, group3)
|-- Example 4 (www.example4.at, group4)
```

Each of these websites offers a frontend login for registered users, who are assigned to a dedicated group.

If a user of group1 logs in via *www.example1.at*, everything works fine - he gets redirected to the user area of group1, let's say *www.example1.at/user_area*.

But if a user of group2 tries to log in via *www.example1.at*, he should be redirected to *www.example2.at/user_area*.

Currently, this does not work. TYPO3s' user group settings only allow a redirect to a page. But since the user area of group2 is only accessible via a dedicated URL, I get the following error:

> ID was outside the domain

Of course this happens because the PID called cannot be accessed via the current URL of *www.example1.at*.

**My question:** is there a way (e.g. via the TSconfig in the user group settings) to redirect to a external URL instead of an internal page on login?

Comment: Only an idea: Did you set [typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#setup-config-typolinkenablelinksacrossdomains)? If not, what happens if you do?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Enabling `typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains` is a partial success - the redirect works without an error. But: the user is not logged in at the destination site, but rather on the source site...

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to remove this setting again. Formhandler could not work correctly anymore.